# .htaccess file: Dynamic redirect

Tags: php, .htaccess, url-rewriting

I've had a hard timing learning rewrite rules in .htaccess files, so I was hoping someone could show me how to rewrite this:

test.com/home/feed/toak/nyheter/vg

into this:

test.com/index.php?r=home&f=feed;toak;nyheter;vg

This is a dynamic URL, and can have multiple elements seperated by ; in the end. I want my users to be able to type in as human friendly URLs as possible. I'm hoping someone can help!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you have variable number of parameters, you can't do it only with .htaccess. You could rewrite in php:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule .* rewrite.php [NE,L]
```

And parse `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']` in rewrite.php.

For static number of 4 variables:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^(\w+)/(\w+)/(\w+)/(\w+)/(\w+) index.php?r=$1&f=$2;$3;$4;$5
```

Or you could do (for any number of variables):

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^(\w+)/(.*) index.php?r=$1&f=$2
```

And use `$_GET['f'] = strtr($_GET['f'], '/', ';');` in index.php.

Comment: Okai, but how do I do this in rewrite.php with a dynamic number of variables?

Comment: `$vars = explode('/', $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']); $r = array_shift($vars); $f = $vars;`