# Redirect page with GET variable htaccess

Tags: php, .htaccess, url-rewriting

Firstly,Thanks for reading this. How to rewrite the url , in htaccess

For example

```
wwww.domain.com/home?name=MuhdNazmi <---OLD URL
wwww.domain.com/home/MuhdNazmi <---NEW URL
```

name is a get variables,

I dont need put .php , since it code for not showing > .php

Comment: Check out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3077451/htaccess-file-dynamic-redirect?rq=1

Comment: can't get it , doesn't solve

Comment: Are you looking for a rewrite rule that does that particular rewrite, or guidance on how to do rewrite rules like that in general?

Comment: in general , any ?name=NAME

Comment: Do names always include just alphabetic characters?

Comment: varchar , a name . maybe varchar

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:

```
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \ /home\?name=([^&\ ]+)
RewriteRule ^ /home/%1? [L,R=301]
RewriteRule ^home/([^/]+)$ /home?name=$1 [L,QSA]
```

Answer (score 0):

RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^home/([^/]*).php$ /home?name=$1 [L]

Answer (score 0):

If it is a one on redirect then you can follow the below example for you redirect

```
    RewriteEngine on
    RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} name=MuhdNazmi$ [NC]
    RewriteRule ^home/$ /home/MuhdNazmi? [L]
```

If you want to define it as a generic rule for all the query string parameter modify the above code as

```
    RewriteEngine on
    RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} name=(.*)$ [NC]
    RewriteRule ^home/$ /home/%1? [L]
```